# Nested selectors in SASS/SCSS

Tags: sass

I am a bit confused with how nested selectors work in SASS/SCSS.

This:

```
#wrapper {
    font: {
        weight: 400;
        size: 13px;
    }
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: #fff;
    > .de1, .de5{margin: auto;}
}
```

compiles to this:

```
#wrapper {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #fff;
}
#wrapper > .de1, #wrapper .de5 {
  margin: auto;
}
```

But what if I wanted to have an end result that does not include `.de5`

```
#wrapper > .de1, .de5 {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Is that even possible? I thought extending the `.de5` selector but that didn't work out.

```
#wrapper {
  font: {
    weight: 400;
    size: 13px;
  }
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #fff;
  > .de1 {margin: auto;}
}
.de5 {@extend .de1;}
```

Compiles to

```
#wrapper {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #fff;
}
#wrapper > .de1, #wrapper > .de5 {
  margin: auto;
}
```

How can I get `.de5` without `#wrapper >`?

(I tested the SCSS on [SassMeister](http://sassmeister.com/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps do it the other way around? Declare the margin for `.de5` and have `#wrapper > .de1` extend that instead:

```
.de5 {
  margin: auto;
}

#wrapper {
  font: {
    weight: 400;
    size: 13px;
  }
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #fff;
  > .de1 {
    @extend .de5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it the other way around.

```
.de5 { margin: auto; }
#wrapper {
    >.de1 { @extend .de5 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a placeholder instead.

**SCSS**

```
%placeholder {
  margin: auto;
}

#wrapper {
    font: {
        weight: 400;
        size: 13px;
    }
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: #fff;

    > .de1 {
      @extend %placeholder;
    }
}

.de5 {
  @extend %placeholder;
}
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper > .de1, .de5 {
  margin: auto;
}

#wrapper {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Link to SassMeister: http://sassmeister.com/gist/32ac4c0aa0f708a0d4e3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same Code for .de1 and .de5 but with different selector, you can use "mixin" and "include". somthing like this:

```
@mixin margin {
margin: auto; 
}
#wrapper {
  font: {
    weight: 400;
    size: 13px;
  }`enter code here`
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #fff;
  > .de1 {@include margin}
}
.de5 {@include margin}
```

I think it can help you.
Live Demo: 
http://sassmeister.com/gist/a19ef9d026a756144cad